# how to return a view in if-else statement LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am new to php and I am wondering how it would be possible to return a view within if-else statement in laravel. I prefer not to use laravel specific stuff, but if I need to, ofc. I will.

Here is a simple example of code, where I check whether the Form input(Name of an author) can go trough validation.If not -I want to show the view with the Form again along with errors, else - DB::insert.. The problem is I can't use return in this case. It will be much appreciated if you can tell me the right way to validate data:
THANK YOU in advance!

```
<?php
 class HomeController extends Controller
    {
    public function authorInput()
        {
        $typeAuthor = Input::get('typeAuthor');
        $author= new Model1();
        $std=$author->checkAuthors($typeAuthor); 
        $bam = array_map(function ($value)          // dolnoto e alternativa
            {
            return (array) $value;
            }, $std);  

        $arr = array();
        if (count($bam) > 0)
            {
            $arr[] = 'This name has already been included';

            }
        if (mb_strlen($typeAuthor) < 2)
            {
            $arr[] = 'The Name should include more than 1 symbol';

            }
        return view('viewAddAuthor', compact('arr'));    
        else
            {
            ....DB::insert
            }
```

Comment: "I prefer not to use laravel specific stuff" Then why use Laravel at all?

Comment: Hi! So that the code could be more structured and to avoid spaghetti :) I will definitely also learn the laravel specifics, but would like to know if raw php could also do the job here

Comment: Laravel is specifically designed to help you avoid spaghetti code. Using Laravel but not using the tools provided by Laravel is a great recipe for spaghetti.

Comment: Laravel has very good validation handling out of the box. Just check it out instead of producing the mess :)

Comment: Thank you, I will then go for $validator = \Validator($data, $rules);                       if ($validator->fails())